# can we sort by attribute value in xml?

Tags: xml, sorting

From below example, can we sort by "gid" values?
Is there a tool or application to achieve this?

My goal: we have duplicate submission of xml files. gid is our unique identifier. I'm planning to sort by gid, compare files and merge changes from all files into one file (to remove redundancy).

Data in xml:

```
<EntityLinkData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <e fid="FMLY1" gid="b5823291-ee16-4fbd-a566-97b6d210f6e8">
        <flds>
            <fld>
                <k>First_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Sarah</v>
            </fld>
            <fld>
                <k>Last_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Connor</v>
            </fld>
        </flds>
    </e>
    <e fid="FMLY2" gid="b5823291-ee16-4fbd-a566-97b6d210f6e9">
        <flds>
            <fld>
                <k>First_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">John</v>
            </fld>
            <fld>
                <k>Last_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Connor</v>
            </fld>
        </flds>
    </e>
    <e fid="FMLY3" gid="b5823291-ee16-4fbd-a566-97b6d210f6e7">
        <flds>
            <fld>
                <k>First_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Kyle</v>
            </fld>
            <fld>
                <k>Last_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Reese</v>
            </fld>
        </flds>
    </e>
</EntityLinkData>
```

Expected output:

```
<EntityLinkData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <e fid="FMLY3" gid="b5823291-ee16-4fbd-a566-97b6d210f6e7">
        <flds>
            <fld>
                <k>First_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Kyle</v>
            </fld>
            <fld>
                <k>Last_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Reese</v>
            </fld>
        </flds>
    </e>
    <e fid="FMLY1" gid="b5823291-ee16-4fbd-a566-97b6d210f6e8">
        <flds>
            <fld>
                <k>First_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Sarah</v>
            </fld>
            <fld>
                <k>Last_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Connor</v>
            </fld>
        </flds>
    </e>
    <e fid="FMLY2" gid="b5823291-ee16-4fbd-a566-97b6d210f6e9">
        <flds>
            <fld>
                <k>First_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">John</v>
            </fld>
            <fld>
                <k>Last_Name</k>
                <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Connor</v>
            </fld>
        </flds>
    </e>
</EntityLinkData>
```

Comment: You can use XSLT for your task.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution via XSLT.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/EntityLinkData">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="e">
                <xsl:sort select="./@gid"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<EntityLinkData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <e fid="FMLY3" gid="b5823291-ee16-4fbd-a566-97b6d210f6e7">
    <flds>
      <fld>
        <k>First_Name</k>
        <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Kyle</v>
      </fld>
      <fld>
        <k>Last_Name</k>
        <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Reese</v>
      </fld>
    </flds>
  </e>
  <e fid="FMLY1" gid="b5823291-ee16-4fbd-a566-97b6d210f6e8">
    <flds>
      <fld>
        <k>First_Name</k>
        <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Sarah</v>
      </fld>
      <fld>
        <k>Last_Name</k>
        <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Connor</v>
      </fld>
    </flds>
  </e>
  <e fid="FMLY2" gid="b5823291-ee16-4fbd-a566-97b6d210f6e9">
    <flds>
      <fld>
        <k>First_Name</k>
        <v xsi:type="xsd:string">John</v>
      </fld>
      <fld>
        <k>Last_Name</k>
        <v xsi:type="xsd:string">Connor</v>
      </fld>
    </flds>
  </e>
</EntityLinkData>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using StyleSheets you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
     <xsl:sort select="artist"/>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_sort.asp